# DOM elements loading on input change in field, not when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, dom

I have a form within a React app where the Input fields are rendered in one component, and the Update/Cancel buttons are rendered in a sibling component.  When this page loads, the input fields are populated with the data from the DB.  I'm creating a function in the Button component that disables the Update button if any of the Input fields are empty.

In the function I set the input fields to a variable by their class name to store the NodeList.  My issue is that even though the function gets called when the page loads, it does not update the variable when the Input fields have been populated with the DB data.  Instead, the variables get set once a user has typed in any of the fields.  Additionally, the variables get set to the field's previous value, rather than its current value.  For example, if I type the letter "A" into an empty field, the DOM variable will read the current value as empty.  If I then type "S" into that same field, the DOM variable will read the value as "A" instead of "AS".

Below is the function I've currently written:

```
  disableButtonCheck = () => {
    const dataField1 = $('.InputField__input___i2o8Y');

    if (dataField1.length > 0) {
      // console.log('hitting conditional')
      const dataValueArray = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < dataField1.length; i += 1) {
        if (dataField1[i].defaultValue === '') {
          console.log('new array:', dataValueArray)
          dataValueArray.push(dataField1[i]);
        }

        if (dataValueArray.length === 0) {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }
    }

    // return true;
  }
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions regarding this or need any additional info.

Comment: Need more context to really say anything, but it seems to me you are doing multiple things the way they are not meant to be done. Really cannot say much from this code snipped.One thing that I can say though is, your function should not be made inside the button component, rather injected as a property by the parent that holds the button and the inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this a couple ways.  The first way was to call the NodeList using Vanilla JS instead of jQuery, since jQuery will add additional keys to the NodeList besides the actual elements.  I then changed the conditionals so that if the NodeList is empty OR if the `dataValueArray` array has a value, then return `true`, otherwise return `false`.  Function is now working as expected.